# my excel2003 toolbar is missing after export

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports

i am using code below to export my report to excel, it work fine in excel2007, but for excel2003, the toolbar is missing, i cant even save, what is the matter that happen?

```
  strFileName = Server.MapPath(EIMSCore.SysConfigEngine.SysConfig.fncGetExportFolderPath()) & "Report" & strFileID.NewGuid().ToString() & ".xls"
                crDiskFileDesOpts.DiskFileName = strFileName
                crExportOpts.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.Excel
                crMainReport.Export()
                'mersad00
                EIMSCore.EIMSCommon.General.ReleaseReportObject(crMainReport)
                With Response
                    .ClearContent()
                    .ClearHeaders()
                    .ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
                    .WriteFile(crDiskFileDesOpts.DiskFileName)
                    .Flush()
                    .Close()
                End With
```

Answer (score 0):

That’s not necessarily a problem of your code. Try to reset the Excel toolbar by opening the registry, navigating to `\HKEY_CURRENT_USER \ Software \ Microsoft \ Office \ <Version> \ Common \ Toolbars \ Settings` and delete the Microsoft Excel entry (after making a backup, of course). Then run your code again and see if the toolbar is disappearing again.

But I suspect it is a coincidence.